# Selenium unable to find element by ID in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate email printing with Selenium & Chrome Driver; for some reason, the snippet below works fine when I exclude the `options=options` argument (i.e. not in headless mode). When I switch headless on, even specifying window size it still is unable to find the element by ID.

#### Config

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep


#-----------------DEFAULT CONFIG

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")
options.add_argument("--allow-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

PATH = '/Users/*********/2021/selenium/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=options)
```

#### Failing Block (last line)

```
    google_login = 'https://accounts.google.com/Login#identifier'
    driver.get(google_login)
    sleep(2)
    html = driver.page_source.strip()

    # =============EMAIL BOX
    user_name = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
```

Error Traceback: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="identifierId"]"}`

I've tried using `WebDriverWait` in a try/except which also doesn't help.

Screenshot captured in headless mode attached (line prior to the failing step) [image]

Answer (score 0):

see headless mode is bit fast so I would suggest you to use it with Explicit waits :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
user_name = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "identifierId")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[Refer here for more](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to help either, I originally had this in my code but removed it when the result was the same. Not sure why headless makes that much of a difference.

Comment: `identifierId`, what element is that in UI ? I could not find that in UI

Comment: `identifierId` is the id which relates to the input box on accounts.google where the user enters their gmail address or phone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```

Please try this.

```
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
```

Comment: Afraid both of these don't make a difference, i've seen other stack answers suggesting to use the former also.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot in the headless mode in case of failure and see it?

Comment: Do you mean a screenshot of the traceback? As headless mode means the browser window doesn't open..

Comment: No, I mean using listener or something similar to take a screenshot in case of exception causing the test to fail

Comment: I've added the image in the original comment - its as is without headless, except in this instance it can't seem to find the ID (but finds it fine when headless is off)